# It inflate the view without the margin

Tags: android, margin, inflate, android-inflate, layout-inflater

I have this code

```
View item = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_layout, null);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(item, params);
```

my item_layout: (note the part android:layout_marginTop="2dip")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="2dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/pic_unknown" android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_height="50dip" android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:padding="5dip"></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then in my layout I see the list of items inflated but with no margin in-between them. I tried with margintop=10dip still nothings happen my point is that the value I put in the layout it is not taken in the calculation with or without the margin top the layout is the same.

How can I add some empty space between the items ?
How can I inflate a empty space between the items ?
Is it possible to inflate something like gap or some space ?
or I must use workaround like inflating some empty layout with 2dip height or something
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The last parameter of the inflate method is the parameter to which you add the inflated view. In your case it is `null`. Try this instead:

```
 View item = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_layout, layout);
```

Comment: Good Suggestion. it is the attachToRoot.

Comment: The problem I have is I'm inflating a `View` to attach it to a `ListView` as a header; if I use the `ListView` in the inflater it throws an exception.  How would I get the margins in this instance?

Comment: whats the layout ?

Comment: @SalehMosleh The parent view. The view to which you want your we to be added.

Answer (score 3):

Try Padding the RelativeLayout instead if your margins apply to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin to layout which you inflated like below:

```
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         params.topMargin = 10;
```